# Extend the line to the end of the screen

Tags: android, math, geometry, formula

I am making an android app which have two circles, there is a line attach between two circles. I have managed to draw a line between the circles regardless the angle between them. The question is I would like to extend that line to the end of the screen. Can I know how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far and screenshots that explains situations?

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded the picture at this link http://i59.tinypic.com/6joqc8.png, as you can see there is two circles with a line, I like to extend that line to the end of the screen both side. The circles is able to move by drag with finger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the co-ordinates of the two circle centres be (a,b) and (c,d).

The line segment you want to draw goes from (p,?) to (q,?) where p and q are the x-co-ordinates of the left and right of the screen. You can use:

```
y = ((d - b)/(c - a))*(p - a) + b
y = ((d - b)/(c - a))*(q - a) + b
```

to find the two y-values of those points. You will encounter a problem if the two points are vertical (c = a) which will cause division by zero.

Comment: You are most welcome. It occurs to me that if the points are nearly vertical, you may get very large values of p and q. If so, it may be better to calculate (?,p) and (?,q) where p and q are the y-co-ordinates of the top and bottom of the screen. Let me know if you want the formula for that. Best wishes.